# Partition names in ADLA Tools. Is it bug or feature?

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

Some of my tables are partitioned. But when i expanded the partitions node a saw that they have a very cryptic names. I know guys you gonna implement catalog views in the future, but may be it will be easy to implement showing partition key **label** instead of a cryptic guid (partition **name**) in the near upcoming refresh ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good suggestion. Can you please file it via http://aka.ms/adlfeedback?

I am also forwarding this post to the tools team.